# Boolean vector comparison for TRUE/FALSE single results

Tags: r, boolean-logic

Imagine I've got a logical vector with the next structure:

```
logical.vector = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

I want to check if it possess a specific patron, the way I thought was doing:

```
logical.vector == c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
-------------------------------------------------
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

What is the proper code to practise the test to obtain a single FALSE output

Comment: You can wrap with `all` i.e. `all(logical.vector == c(TRUE, FALSE))` or use `identical` or `all.equal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `all` as suggested in the comment by @akrun, one could take the slightly more "backwards" approach of using `any`, which evaluates to `true` if *at least a one* element in a vector is true -- in your example, one element is the same as the standard with respect to its index and value. By evaluating this (*input*) with !*input*, meaning NOT *input*, you can obtain the result you are after.

```r
# Standard
logical.vector = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

# Test Patterns

# Case 1 (non-match): should be FALSE
!any(logical.vector != c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
 
# Case 2 (non-match): should be FALSE
!any(logical.vector != c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)) 

# Case 3 (non-match): should be FALSE
!any(logical.vector != c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)) 

# Case 4 (non-match): should be FALSE
!any(logical.vector != c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)) 

# Case 5 (match): should be TRUE
!any(logical.vector != c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```